# Error using Session Id auth with cURL following REST documentation

Tags: apex, api, force.com, oauth, curl

Problem: trying to authenticate to a dev org using Session Id authentication and cURL fails when following the REST API Dev doc. The example in the doc provides the following, which fails (Quick Start pg:23):

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d
"client_id=myclientid" -d "client_secret=myclientsecret" -d "mylogin@salesforce.com" -d
"password=mypassword123456"
```

Even after appending the security token to the password, the response is the same:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation has a bug in it. Following the documentation, your cURL command would look like this:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d 
"client_id=XXXXXX.YYYYY_ZZZZZ" -d "client_secret=000099990000" -d "name@domain.com" -d 
"password=yourpasswordyoursecuritytoken"
```

It's missing the username= parameter. Change it to the following and it will work for you:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d 
"client_id=XXXXXX.YYYYY_ZZZZZ" -d "client_secret=000099990000" -d "username=name@domain.com" -d 
"password=yourpasswordyoursecuritytoken"
```

Comment: Good find. Are you aware you can report this directly to Salesforce? [Here is the html version of the page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/quickstart_oauth.htm) At the bottom of the page there is the section: Was this information helpful?, and the link *Yes, except*. Where you can put all the details you have posted in this question and answer. I don't know how proactive they are with the feedback they receive, so it may get ignored. But it's better than nothing

Comment: The feedback form directly logs a case with the doc writer team, and is by far the best way to give feedback & get the docs improved.

Comment: This is good to know. Thanks. I gave up on logging cases when they changed the rules to disallow dev orgs to file them. But I'll post this on the feedback form.

Comment: I stubmled across this today - proof positive that the documentation hasn't been corrected in 9 months

Comment: Too bad. I logged this on the feedback form back when it happened. This is why the StackExchange isn't going anywhere.