# Salesforce REST API example, error: failed with status 400

Tags: rest-api, rest-service, php

I am going through this [example](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php) of REST web service to salesforce from PHP app, and I was getting the same errors described [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/APIs-and-Integration/token-failed-with-status-0/td-p/228297). I tried to implement more permanent solution with

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\dev\curl\cacert.pem');

from here http://kb.ucla.edu/articles/how-do-i-use-curl-in-php-on-windows .

I downloaded cacert.pem from this link http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html .

It works for the example with google ("https://encrypted.google.com/";) , but does not work with salesforce. I am getting the following error:

Error: call to token URL https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed with status 400, curl_errno() 0, curl_error() , response {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}

Any ideas please how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your curl command?

Also are you passing the security token?

Please see this. Have you passed the username param?
[Error using Session Id auth with cURL following REST documentation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5206/error-using-session-id-auth-with-curl-following-rest-documentation)

If you are using Mac or Linux, see this:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_curl.htm