# Connected App Error - { "error_description": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "expired access/refresh token" }

Tags: api, rest, oauth2

I've have successfully created a connected app using our sandbox account by following this [Enable oauth settings api integration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_create_api_integration.htm&type=5), However when I try to request for access_token I'm getting the follow error response:

```
{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "expired access/refresh token'\n" }
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this response but here's my request parameters and the url I'm sending it to.

```
const params = {
  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "code" :"code_from_saleforce",
  "client_id": "sf_clientID",
  "client_secret": "sf_clientSecret",
  "redirect_uri": "https://someurl.com/callback",
};

const url = "https://company_instance.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";
```

I'm a bit confuse of the error because at line of my code I'm still request for access_token with the **code** from salesforce and I'm obviously not sending any access_token/refresh token to salesforce.

I also tried the solutions provide in this posting [Invalid Grant | Authentication problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44171/issues-with-connected-app-error-descriptionauthentication-failure-error) but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @shark, do you want to use your authorization grant_type as 'authorization_code' only ? or will 'password' also work for you ?

Comment: I only use "authorization_code"

Comment: I'm actually following this flow https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: any one kind enough to explain what's causing this issue?